# Button label jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

I want to change button label in jQuery DataTable.

That's my code (not working)

```
        $('#data-table').dataTable({
            "language":
                {
                    "paginate":
                        { "next": "Next page" }
                }
        });
```

I'm still have Next label.

Comment: could you please http://jsfiddle.net/ your code?

Comment: which version of data table you are using?

Comment: @MokshShah I can't past all my code.

Comment: @SameerAzazi //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine check here: http://jsfiddle.net/w30jpdk2/

Comment: Hi, any idea how I can change the label of the page numbers from 1 to One, I have tried various options but no luck so far! Appreciate any ideas

Answer (score 0):

More elaboration of the problem would have definitely helped in answering.Still, it's a common problem faced across as to how to represent options.

It seems the initialization option you are using is not correct i.e. "language","paginate","next", etc.

Whatever version of datatable you are using-get inside that js file and search for initialization options that can be given to `dataTables` at initialization time. For some version it may be like `oLanguage` for others it may be `sLanguage`, `language`,`aLanguage` and so on. Look for the correct representation of `language`, `paginate`, `next` that you are using.

e.g/ I'm using datatable version which has slightly different representation which I used like this:

```
"oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": 'No Data Avalaible',
    "oPaginate": {
        "sNext": 'Next Page',
        "sPrevious":'Previous Page'
    },
    "sSearch": 'Search Inside'
}
```

Also if possible press F12 and have a look at the console window if any errors are coming.

Thanks for asking. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```js
/* DATATABLE ---- */ 
$('.my_datatable').DataTable({
  "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "show _MENU_ records per page",
    "zeroRecords": "No records",
    "info": "Showing _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
    "infoEmpty": "No records available",
    "infoFiltered": "(filter from _MAX_ records)",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sNext": "Next page",
      "sPrevious": "Previous page",
      "sFirst": "First",
      "sLast": "Last"
    }
  },
});
```